# Fix or reallocate a Bad Sector

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

It takes a long time for Ubuntu to boot on my Machine.
I ran check and recover bad Sectors from the BIOS and it gave me one bad sector.
I got similar result using gsmartcontrol
RESULT:

```
Error 407 [150] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9895 hours (412 days + 7 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
-- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 21 ed b0 08 e1 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x21edb008 = 569225224

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
42 00 21 00 00 00 00 21 ed b0 09 e0 00     04:30:13.060  READ VERIFY SECTOR(S) EXT
42 00 21 00 00 00 00 21 ed b0 09 e0 00     04:30:09.082  READ VERIFY SECTOR(S) EXT
42 00 21 00 00 00 00 21 ed b0 09 e0 00     04:30:05.103  READ VERIFY SECTOR(S) EXT
42 00 21 00 00 00 00 21 ed b0 09 e0 00     04:30:01.125  READ VERIFY SECTOR(S) EXT
42 00 21 00 00 00 00 21 ed b0 09 e0 00     04:29:57.147  READ VERIFY SECTOR(S) EXT
```

The Bad sector here is 569225224.
I tried:

```
 sudo hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --write-sector 569225224 /dev/sda
```

Could someone help me with a way to fix the Bad sector or at least remove it from being used ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This one bad sector is just the front for a whole series of bad sectors that have consumed all sectors set aside for this. The drive is in failure mode; replace it ASAP.

Comment: are there no work arounds for this ??

Comment: The drive is not *starting* to die, it is **continuing** to die.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **badblocks** command, but it is only compatible with certain file systems.

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda10 > badsectors.txt
```

------------ Specifically for ext2/ext3/ext4 file-systems ------------

```
 sudo e2fsck -l badsectors.txt /dev/sda10
```

OR
------------ For other file-systems ------------

```
sudo fsck -l badsectors.txt /dev/sda10
```